# how to get only the specific content from a file using PHP.

Tags: php

how to get only the specific content from a file using PHP.

I have a file with content:

```
reference 1.pdb
mobile 4r_1.pdb
ignore
fit
mobile 4r_10.pdb
ignore
fit
mobile 4r_22220.pdb
ignore
fit
```

Now, I want to take all the names i.e. (output)

```
4r_1
4r_10
4r_22220
```

in an array and print it.

The program i have written in php doesn't work properly, can have a look

```
$data = file_get_contents('file.txt'); // to read the file
$convert = explode("\n", $data); // take it in an array
$output4 = preg_grep("/mobile/i",$convert); //take only the line starts with mobile and put it in an array
if ($output4 !="/mobile/i")
{ 
print $output4;
print "\n";
}
```

Please help! to extract only the names

Comment: Try `var_dump($output4);`

Comment: I would probably first search for lines that contain `pdb`, then just find the right most space, and explode/keep the the right most value.

Comment: Find `mobile` and substr the right side of it in each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$convert = explode("\n", $data); // take it in an array
$filenames = array();


foreach ($convert as $item) {
    if(strstr($item,'mobile')) {
        array_push($filenames,preg_replace('/mobile[\s]?([A-Za-z0-9_]*).pdb/','${1}',$item));
    }
}
```

Now all the file names (assuming they are file names) are in the array `$filenames`

Comment: Thankssssssssssss a lot :)

Comment: No problem. You could probably work on that regex a little. Right now it's pretty specific to what you posted.

Comment: but when i print the array it prints in the way  4r_1 , 4r_1 , 4r_10 where $filenames[0] => 4r_1  and $filenames[1] => 4r_1, 4r_10. But i want $filenames[0] => 4r_1 and $filenames[1] => 4r_10. :(

Comment: @user1971853, do a `var_dump($filenames)`. I bet you the array is just fine and the way you are iterating through is not. [Here's a PHPFiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/304-mrt) with the exact same code showing it to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

preg_grep returns an array of matching lines, your condition is treating $output4 as a string.

Loop over the array to print out each line and use either substr or str_replace to remove the unwanted characters from the string

```
$data = file_get_contents('test.txt'); // to read the file
$convert = explode("\n", $data); // take it in an array
$output4 = preg_grep("/mobile/i",$convert); //take only the line starts with mobile and put it in an array
foreach($output4 as $entry) {
    print str_replace("mobile ", "", $entry) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work:

```
$data = file_get_contents('file.txt'); // to read the file
$convert = explode("\n", $data); // take it in an array
$output4 = preg_grep("/mobile/i",$convert);
if (count($output4))
{ 
   foreach ($output as $line) {

      print $line; // or substr($line, 6) to remove mobile from output
      print "\n";
   }
}
```

**Note:**

Instead of doing

```
$data = file_get_contents('file.txt'); // to read the file
$convert = explode("\n", $data); // take it in an array
```

You may read a file into array with [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function:

```
$convert = file('file.txt'); // to read the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^mobile\s+(.+)$/', $line, $match)) {
        echo $match[1], "\n";
    }
}
```